# From my results, the quotient of two derivatives should not be defined for functions which are continuous at $x$?

Tags: limits

I apologize for such a stupid question, but given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, we could state that the $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}$, now this implies that given $f$ and $g$ which are continuous at $x$, then $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is undefined, something that should not be true. What's going on here?

Note that if this is a duplicate, please comment, I did not know what to look up for such a problem, I have asked a friend above me and he said he could not spot anything wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps start with a simple example, e.g. $f(x) = g(x) = x$. These are continuous, and $f'(x)/g'(x) = 1/1$ does exist. Can you see where your argument is wrong?

Comment: *Why* do you think that $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}$ implies that $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ is undefined?

Comment: My above example shows that this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your argument. *Why* should the fraction be $0/0$?

Comment: Yes, both numerator and denominator tend to zero. But that does not prevent the quotient from having a limit. Example: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac x x = 1$.

Comment: In fact, in **any** derivative of a continuous function, you have a limit where both numerator and denominator go to zero. The whole edifice of limits was constructed to be able to figure out what that actually means, and the answer is not to throw out our hands in despair every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that both numerator and denominator in
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{g(x+h)-g(x)}
$$
tend to zero for $h \to 0$ if both $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$. But that does not tell anything about the limit of the fraction: It can be non-existent, infinity, or some finite number. If we write the fraction as
$$
\frac{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}x}{\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}x}
$$
then we can see that the limit for $h \to 0$ is $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$, provided that

- $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$,
- $g(x+h) - g(x) \ne 0$ for all sufficiently small $h$, and
- $g'(x) \ne 0$.

This also follows from [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), which is a consequence of [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy%27s_mean_value_theorem).